ERD issue for an webpage that accepts booking then provides the appropriate students to send
ERD
What seems to be the issue? We have an ERD for school-based event management system wherein the event organizer doesn't have to login hence he/she can be associated on the organizer_booking table. What seems to be the issue (circled) on the image that our ERD is said to be incorrect?
